# Validate hibernate mapping file against database for ALL differences

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need to validate my hibernate mapping file against some databases. We have quite a complicated schema, and for various reasons we have different branches of the schema on various different databases. So I want to be able to compare my hibernate mapping files with a database. I have tried the

```
hbm2ddl=validate
```

flag, but this throws an error on the first difference it finds and stops. Is there any way to carry on and print ALL differences? Or some plugin for hibernate or some other free tool I can use that will do this?

I have looked at something like Liquibase, and will go down this route if it's the best option, but it seems like since I already have hibernate set up, some config I can change or a plugin that I can just drop in would be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate HBMDDL tool is not the best tool for incrementally updating a database schema. It's useful as an initial script generators, but from then on you should use Liquibase or [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/).

I can also recommend you a [Hibernate Integration Testing Strategy Guide](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-integration-testing-strategies/), which elaborates why having an incremental update solution is a better fit.

This way you don't need to validate the schema, since both the production and the development environment will share the same schema.

Then Hibernate just needs to map the existing schema to your domain model classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Moving to Liquibase to manage our databases is something we are ultimately working towards, but for now we have a bunch of different databases in slightly different states and need to know what those differences are (and the databases have data in them, so we can't just drop and recreate)

Comment: I can recommend DBSolo, but it's not free software.